# "Yarn hardhat test" returning "0 passing" confusion

Tags: javascript, solidity

https://github.com/WillStansill/Hardhat-fund-me

Hey guys I'm going through a tutorial and having a problem that's held me up for a couple days now. When I try and run "yarn hardhat test" even if I copy and paste over the exact code from GitHub provided it will still tell me "0 passing" when it should be passing 7 tests. What's made this really confusing for me is someone tried to help me by looking into my repository I have pasted above and they said the test ran no problems with it passing 7. I have tried running "hardhat clean" deleting the node modules and redownloading them to see if it was an issue with my dependencies and that hasn't seem to be a solution either. If anyone has any potential solutions or directions to look towards I would be incredibly appreciative because this has halted my progression to learning to code until I can get it figured out. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test files are in the `test` folder. And your test folder should be in your project folder/directory.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem, but just noticed that in my first describe. I used an async callback function instead of a asynchronous one.

i.e. Change `async() =>{}` to `function(){}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).